# Calendar.apk running problem?

Tags: android

I have an apk of Calendar application. I have installed the apk on android 2.1 API level 7 emulator successfully. But the problem is I can not run the application. When I click on the app icon it shows the following message.
Sorry! The appliaction Calendar(process com.android.calendar) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. (It is a Force close message)

if anyone knows the solution pls tell me.

BR,
gsmaker

Comment: This site is to ask question about *programming* only.

Comment: Is this not related to programming?

Answer (score 1):

Up until at least android 2.1 the emulator was incapable of syncing with google accounts and thus the calendar (which requires syncing) will not run even if you install it.

This might work on 2.2 now that you can input a google account, but that is not certain (especially if you have an old version of the calendar APK).

What is certain though is that if you want to test the calendar application on android 2.1 or earlier you'll need a real test device, sorry.